# Help Sorting Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using to keep track of stats for players in a league. This is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/193GxNzaX4-bGrNB8eT4vhqAOKhUrChRDgq-HYVU_Txk/edit#gid=1738544316

What I'm trying to have it do, is search the "Stats Gathering" sheet for the value in the `C` Column. When it finds that value, I want it to return the value of the `A` Column on the "Stats Gathering" sheet, i.e. their name.

I looked up a guide on youtube and it told me to importrange, which i did. This is the formula I've been using:

`=VLOOKUP(C3, importrange("193GxNzaX4-bGrNB8eT4vhqAOKhUrChRDgq-HYVU_Txk", "Stats Gathering!A3:W43"), 1, FALSE)`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to mention. The error it's giving says it can't find the value '10.5' in VLOOKUP evaluation. So essentially, anything in the `C` column, it says it can't find it in the importrange, even though it's in there.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of 249 static formulas you can use just 3 dynamic ones.**

For your 1st set use the following on cell `A3`

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(((IFERROR( 
       VLOOKUP(SORT('solution Stats Gathering'!K3:K,1,0),
                  ({'solution Stats Gathering'!K3:K,'solution Stats Gathering'!A3:L}),{2,3,12},0)
      )))),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

For the 2nd set use this one

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(((IFERROR( 
       VLOOKUP(SORT('solution Stats Gathering'!I3:I,1,0),
                  ({'solution Stats Gathering'!I3:I,'solution Stats Gathering'!A3:L}),{2,3,10},0)
      )))),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

For the 3rd set use

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(((IFERROR( 
       VLOOKUP(SORT('solution Stats Gathering'!J3:J,1,0),
                  ({'solution Stats Gathering'!J3:J,'solution Stats Gathering'!A3:L}),{2,3,11},0)
      )))),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Please have a look at the [SAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tGNb_7rHBOzIpq50av86AFnV5v2sp0WIQxRDBBX3ocY/edit#gid=301225686&range=A3) I prepared for you.

If you still want to use the static formulas then, the formula you need for your first line of your first set of data is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,ArrayFormula({stats!$K$3:$K$44,stats!$A$3:$W$44}),2,0)
```

You can then copy it down and the the right changing the cells/ranges accordingly.

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)

Comment: Have you tried the dynamic query formulas? Did they work for you? I would love to know. As always, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.