# How can I color the target of a SUM formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

If I double click on a formula with a cell range, Google Sheets will outline the target area:

[image]

Is there a way to get similar highlighting at all times, updated as the range or ranges in the formulas are updated?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are looking for a **hover "effect"**.
If that is the case, **you can not**.
*(Try visualizing what it would look like -in a common scenario- moving your cursor around a sheet with many long formulas, in close range with inter-lapping ranges and cells like one with [249 ones](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139296))*

You could **send a feature request to Google**.
Go to the top menu, `Help` >> `Report a problem` and fill out the pop-up form